# How to add a rotate animation to a background image on a separate thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation

I'm building an app where I want a small rotating image in one of the corners under the other content. I have created an animation xml file and I am currently loading the animation in my main activity.

Unfortunately this seems to be slowing the app down and the log output indicates that frames are being skipped because 'The application may be doing too much work on its main thread'. So I think the best thing to do would be to move the animation to a new thread?

Here's how I'm animating the image currently:

```
ImageView rotatingCog

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rotatingCog = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bgCog);
    final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(rootView.getContext(), R.anim.rotate_cog);
    rotatingCog.startAnimation(animRotate);

    ...

}
```

How can I move this code to a new thread and start that thread when this fragment is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 Thread animationThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
   @Override public void run(){
        mHandler.post(animateView);
   }

 });

 animationThread.start();
  ...
}

 Runnable animateView = new Runnable(){
    @Override public void run(){
       final ImageView rotatingCog = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.bgCog);
       final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),     R.anim.rotate_cog);
      rotatingCog.startAnimation(animRotate);
   }

 };


}
```

Comment: Perfect, It ran first time and has really made the animation so much smoother! Thanks for the help.

Comment: i think i was finding the view wrong, update to call getView() instead of getActivity(), but glad i could help something else to make note of i would only inflate the view in onCreateView(), then do all your animating in onViewCreated() to make sure the fragment has actually created the view first before accessing UI elements